# How can you change a watch face name for Android Wear

Tags: android, wear-os

I've been using the codelabs tutorial on making a watch found here:
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/watchface/index.html#0

I've got my watch to a level where I would like to publish it on the Play store, but cannot work out how to change the name from "Analog Codelab Watchface." This name only appears when selecting the watchface.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it's set in the manifest file.

android:label="Your Name here"